# read property file using embed angular project inside spring boot app

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have an angular embedded in spring boot project. With using angular 6 and spring boot. All are fine. My angular index.html file is in resources of spring boot app. I want to read spring boot properties in angular html file. Please help me.

Comment: please read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section.

Answer (score 0):

The angular application doesn't have access to the spring boot properties, because the angular application runs in the users' browser, and the spring boot app runs on the server.

Your only chance is to manually create REST services, which return the properties, and you can call those services from the angular app.